# Cruisecontrol.net how I can get value of a parameter and pass into Labeller plugin

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

```
<project name="My Project" queue="1" queuePriority="1">
   <labeller type="MyLabeller">
        <MyNumber>myProject_${MyNumber}</MyNumber>
   </labeller>  

<parameters>
            <selectParameter name="MyNumber">
                <description>Select RC number</description>
                <display>RC build</display>
                <allowedValues>
                    <value name="None">0</value>
                    <value name="data1">1</value>
                    <value name="data2">2</value>
                </allowedValues>
                <default>0</default>
                <required>true</required>
            </selectParameter>
</parameters>

</project>
```

I wrote a Labeller plugin named MyLabeller. I want when user choose MyNumber in UI when they force a new build. The value of MyNumber will be passed into MyLabeller plugin. I try to use the following syntax but no luck.

myProject_${MyNumber}

If user choose 1, My Number has to be myProject_1.
if user choose 2, My Number has to be myProject_2.

So are there any ways to do this ? Thanks.

p/s: currently, I use cruisecontrol.net version 1.8.4.0

Answer (score 2):

parameter references use square brackets $[parameter name]

Be ware that parameters are not updated for pre-build.

You can also set environemnt variable ... value = $[parameter name] within an executable task but remember the variable value will only exist for the duration of the executable command.